# use appinsights in an on-premise web server

Tags: azure-application-insights, appinsights

We would like to use appinsights to collect data for our on-premise sites.

I found an article https://unhandled.wordpress.com/2018/02/01/using-azure-application-insights-with-on-premises-servers/

which will install an old (2016) software (Application Insights Status Monitor).
Is it still the right way to use appinsight in an on-premise web server?

Comment: I read through appinsight sdk code, looks like that if I include appinsight nuget package and provide the right instrument key, it may just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to instrument on-premise web server.

Option I: Use [Status Monitor v2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/application-insights-status-monitor-v2-is-now-generally-available/) to auto-instrument your application. No need to change code.

Option II: Add [Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) to your web application project. Redeploy your application.